# Exchange 2010 IMAP only allowing 1 active user

Tags: exchange-2010, imap

we recently switched to exchange 2010 (clean install) and we are having an issue with our IMAP account only allowing 1 person to be in it at a time. The rest get kicked back and given the option to enter a new email/password. We use this for our support department and their emails so we need everyone logged in and able to see if a message has been read ect (thus the need for IMAP). I know they can use the OWA shell but do you guys know if there is a setting to allow multiple users in IMAP?

This is with all POP3/IMAP accounts. they limit it to 1 person being logged in/setup at a time.

thanks!

Comment: If anyone knows how to configure multiple active exchange accounts that would work too. When i set it up it asks for the login credentials for both exchange accounts even though they are logged into one (domain account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it had to do with the netlogon service. once that was started everything seemed to work correctly